email server (paid or unpaid) with multiple accounts where each has separate inbox, sent box, etc
I am looking for an email server (not an email client) that offers multiple addresses where each address has it's own inbox, sent box, trash, junk mail, etc.  A paid service is fine. I do not want one that offers multiple addresses where all mail goes into one inbox and needs to be sorted out.  I want essentially separate email accounts for 4 addresses under one master account.
Any info?   thanks,     tom kosvic

Have you tried Fastmail?
